# Memory allocation in IBM AIX fails using xlc compiler?

Tags: c++, c, xlc

In my code is necessary to allocate several large arrays.

However, when I try to use the IBM xlc_r :

`xlc_r -g  -O -L. -qarch=pwr7 -qtune=pwr7 -lesslsmp -lm -qsmp -qthreaded -qmaxmem=-1 2.c`

```
int main()
{
     int natom = 5000;
     while(1)
     {
        double *z =(double*) malloc(natom*natom*natom* sizeof(double));
        if(!z)
        {  
           printf("error memory vector z\n\n");
           exit(-1);
        }
     }
}
```

I receive either Killed an error for memory vector z.

This is the `ulimit -a` :

> ```
> core file size          (blocks, -c) unlimited
> ```

```
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited 
open files                      (-n) 102400   
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 64   
stack size              (kbytes, -s) unlimited   
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited   
max user processes              (-u) 128  
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
```

Is there any flag necessary to allocate more memory?

Comment: You do realize you're allocating 500 gigabytes right?  I'm pretty sure your computer doesn't have that much memory.

Comment: @MooingDuck I reckon a terabyte, assuming ieee754 double (64-bit). But another issue is that `natom * natom * natom` will cause integer overflow unless `int` is also 64-bit

Comment: The "Killed" error probably indicates the OS using lazy allocation

Comment: C or C++? Choose one. They're not the same language. And [don't cast the result of malloc in C](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714)

Comment: Rather than `double *z = (double*) malloc(natom*natom*natom* sizeof(double));` use `z = malloc(sizeof *z *natom*natom*natom);`  This is easier to code correctly and avoid overflow as original uses `int` math.  the second uses `size_t` math.

Comment: You need to enable 64b mode with -q64 or something like that. I'll try to write a proper answer with details later.

Comment: @MooingDuck POWER775 machines can be configured with quite a lot of memory. 512GB or 768GB is not out of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hit this issue on a POWER775 AIX machine a while back.  You need to add the `-q64` flag when compiling in order to allocate more than 2GiB of memory.  Note that the comments by others about using `int` may be relevant to your code, which is why my example below uses `size_t`.

I recommend you run a simple test of allocation to investigate this.  My tester that I wrote for this situation is below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    size_t max = (argc>1) ? (size_t)atol(argv[1]) : ((size_t)256*1024)*((size_t)1024*1024);
    for (size_t n=1; n<=max; n*=2) {
        printf("attempting malloc of %zu bytes \n", n);
        fflush(0);
        void * ptr = malloc(n);
        if (ptr==NULL) {
            printf("malloc of %zu bytes failed \n", n);
            fflush(0);
            return 1;
        } else {
            printf("malloc of %zu bytes succeeded \n", n);
            fflush(0);
            memset(ptr,0,n);
            printf("memset of %zu bytes succeeded \n", n);
            fflush(0);
            free(ptr);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The associated build flags were as follows.

```
ifeq ($(TARGET),POWER7-AIX)
# Savba i.e. POWER775 AIX
    CC       = mpcc_r
    OPT      = -q64 -O3 -qhot -qsmp=omp -qtune=pwr7 -qarch=pwr7 -qstrict
    CFLAGS   = $(OPT) -qlanglvl=stdc99
endif
```